# Upload images in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to create a control panel for a web site, so i am trying that my client can upload his pictures for the store, and also a little description, can you give an idea of how can i do that? I am new doing this

Comment: Similar to this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_accept?

Comment: Can you provide a more narrow scope? For example: whats the method of upload? Via the browser, or via a plugin?

Comment: "can you give an idea of how can i do that". Yup. Go find your favorite CMS and install it. Most of them (the decent ones anyway) have this sort of thing built in right out of the box.

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/the-basics-of-file-upload-in-php/). And here is the unbeatable [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create table images in your database

```
Create table images ('id' int primary key auto_increment, 'url' text, 'desc' text);
```

In your panel make form with file input

```
<form action="upload.php>
    <input name='file'>
    <textarea name='desc'>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Write upload.php look at [this](https://gist.github.com/taterbase/2688850)
After upload insert into db record with url and desc.

Get ur records from db and show them all